# How to use instagram basic display API or Graph API

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, kotlin, instagram-api

Right now i have an android app on kotlin. What app actually does on frontend is a user launches app, search any username or name on text bar and it opens the searched profile's picture and shows in Full HD in image view.

TLDR; right now i am using this code to login to Instagram through JavaScript on GitHub which is deployed on Heroku and my android app use Heroku URL to do the things. here is my script:

I have two Instagram usernames. this script picks random username from array and login. password is same for both Instagram accounts.

also, sometimes i get async error in Heroku Logs.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Instagram = require("instagram-web-api");
const FileCookieStore = require("tough-cookie-filestore2");
const cookieStore = new FileCookieStore("./cookies.json");

var isHTML = RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/(<([^>]+)>)/i);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

var usernameArray = [
    
    'instagramusername1',
    'instagramusername2'
];

let randomUsername = usernameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * usernameArray.length)]

const client = new Instagram({
  
  username: (randomUsername), 
  password: "password for both accounts",
  cookieStore,
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello To Your Instagram Server");
});

app.get("/account/:userName", (req, res) => {
  const user_name = req.params.userName;
  (async () => {
    const instagram_user = await client.getUserByUsername({
      username: `${user_name}`,
    });
    res.json(instagram_user);
  })();
});

app.get("/search/:q", (req, res) => {
  const query = req.params.q;
  (async () => {
    const resulte = await client.search({ query: query });

    const data = await JSON.stringify(resulte);
    if (isHTML(String(data))) {
      console.log("Must Login");
      await client.login();
      const tryagin = await client.search({ query: query });
      res.send(tryagin);
    } else {
      console.log("no  login");

      res.send(resulte);
    }
  })();
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    const user = await client.login();
    if (user.authenticated == false) {
      res.status(401).send(user);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(user);
    }
  })();
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  (async () => {
    client.logout();

    res.send({ statu: "Logout" });
    console.log("done");
  })();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```